# Operator shadowing in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parsec

I want to use the `<|>` operator from `Text.Parsec` but I am also importing `Control.Applicative` which also contains a `<|>` operator. How do I make sure that the former operator shadows the latter assuming I don't want to use an ugly looking qualified import?

Comment: As an aside, you probably want to use the `<|>` from `Control.Applicative`, not the one from `Text.Parsec`. The former behaves the same as the latter when applied to parsers, but is generalised to work on other `Alternative`s too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Options you have, in descending order of recommendation:

- Switch to [megaparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec), which is built up front around the existing Haskell functor / transformer classes, rather than defining that kind of stuff anew.
- Hide the unnecessarily specific [`Parsec.<|>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec3-1.0.1.8/docs/Text-Parsec.html#g:2). You don't need it.

  ```
  import Text.Parsec hiding ((<|>))
  import Control.Applicative
  ```
- Hide [`Applicative.<|>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-) and use only the stuff from `Control.Applicative` that's not concerned with alternatives.

  ```
  import Text.Parsec
  import Control.Applicative hiding (Alternative(..))
  ```

Comment: Is there any reason to still be using parsec compared to megaparsec? Seems like megaparsec fixes all the things that annoy me in parsec...

Comment: Thanks for the information on megaparsec. Didn't know of its existence until now.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this would either be a qualified import or an import with hiding

```
import qualified Control.Applicative as CA
import Text.Parsec
```

or if you don't want to use qualified

```
import Control.Applicative hiding ((<|>))
import Text.Parsec
```

Shadowing would not work because both imports live in the same namespace and therefore ghc cannot infer the correct choice of function, i.e. the one you meant.

To my knowledge shadowing only works in function blocks which generate a new scope.

<strike>Moreover the order of imports makes in a lazily evaluated language has its perils and even though I am no expert I would guess that if a library is imported depends whether if it is used or where it is used which would affect the order of import.</strike>

### <strike>update:</strike>

<strike>If there was a name shadowing at the point of imports - then the order of imports would make a difference, which is something you are not used to in  a lazily evaluated language, where usually the order of execution of pure functions is arbitrary (even though the imports are done at compile time as @TikhonJelvis pointed out).</strike>

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your final paragraph. Haskell handles imports statically, at compile time—the fact that it's lazy doesn't matter. Everything you import is in scope and if you try to use a name that is ambiguous, your file just won't compile.

Comment: In particular, the order of imports doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Which function is referenced by a particular identifier has literally nothing to do with evaluation order. If imports were resolved with textually later import declarations shadowing names imported from earlier ones it would *still* have nothing to do with evaluation order. Which is exactly how the shadowing Haskell *does* have (nested name bindings) works; changing the order of evaluation doesn't affect which binding is referenced by an identifier.